# WLP648 does it make a sour?

Tags: yeast

I've been reading up on WLP648, but can't determine if this yeast will develop a sour beer on its own or if it requires something else to become properly sour aside from 3-6 months.

I've read some contradictions, so wanted to confirm what to expect in terms of sourness from this yeast. My goal is to brew a proper sour beer, similar to a Geuze.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at the Milk the Funk Wiki: http://www.milkthefunk.com/wiki/Brettanomyces#Wyeast

> The vrai (true, in French) Brettanomyces bruxellensis Trois. The infamous strain used for all-Brettanomyces fermentations, has a robust, complex sour character with aromas of pear. Best used as a primary fermentation strain.

To answer your question: yes, it sours your beer.

Comment: Will the Brett also make it dry, or is this when adding it to secondary or bottle?

Comment: Typically Brett strains produce dry beers. Careful adding it to bottles with priming sugar as the Brett may be able to ferment some additional sugar left behind by Sacc. yeasts. There could be the potential for bottle bombs.